# jquery is not defined in my jsp code

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I got **jQuery is not defined** in my jsp. The error is here:

> "jQuery('#Frame').animate360({"

In the following code:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        jQuery('#Frame').animate360({
            centerInWindow: true,
            xmlPath: '/',
            objPath: 'Images/',
            iconPath: 'HTML5/Images/'
        });
    };
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: where did you included jquery library? after body? in a parent frame? and where did you load the plugin "animate360"?

Comment: Put this in your header : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
`. If it works, then you just forgot to include the library.

Comment: I already included header in mycode like this :<script type = "text/javascript" src = "HTML5/jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "HTML5/jQueryPlugin.js"></script>

Comment: @sandy444 so do you have the files at those locations? Or does it return 404 if you try to access them directly with your browser?

Comment: yes, i have those files that location....and it was showing in firebug 404 error like "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/madisons/tableware/silverware/HTML5/HTML5Viewer.css"
HTML5Viewer.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/madisons/tableware/silverware/HTML5/jQuery.js"

Comment: What folder is this particular JSP in?

Comment: Are those absolute URL's?  Or are they relative to the file?  You may need to add a leading '/' on those paths.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of things going wrong here. I would recommend going back to basics to make sure jQuery is correctly being loaded in the first place.

1. Download `jquery.js` from: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js
2. Put `jquery.js` into the same folder as your JSP.
3. Update your code above to this:

   ```
   <body>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
           alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
       } else {
           alert("jQuery library is not found!");
       }
   </script>
   </body>
   ```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-check-if-jquery-library-is-loaded/

Once you are sure that jQuery is working, you can then change the where you load it from, e.g.:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="HTML5/jQuery.js"></script>`

If you continue to get the "jQuery library is loaded!" message then you can put back in your window.onload assignment.

Comment: I got alert: jQuery library is not found and in console it is showing networkerror 404 not found.  I replaced my code with your code: <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') { 
        alert("jQuery library is loaded!"); 
    } else { 
        alert("jQuery library is not found!"); 
    } 
</script>

Comment: @sandy444 Did you put the downloaded `jquery.js` into the **same** folder as your JSP?